# How to print name of each file , and content in directory?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

I have many text files in a directory and I want to print each file name and its content. The problem is the content is duplicated from the previous file to the next file. Here is my code:

```
import os
directory = os.listdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
os.chdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
for file in directory:
    open_file = open(file,'r')
    read_file = open_file.read()
    print(open_file.name)
    print("***************")
    print(read_file)
```

it's print out as an example:

```
a.txt
 This is file1.
 ***********
b.txt
This is file1. This file 2
```

..
any suggestion?..Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't close the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't close the files, and you should be using a `with` (which closes the file after you exit), something like this

```
import os

directory = os.listdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')
os.chdir('/Users/user/My Documents/test/')

for file in directory:
    print(file)
    print("***************")    
    with open(file, 'r') as openfile:
        print(openfile.read())
    print('\n')
```